# How do I convert a python array of shape (25000, 256,256,3) to (25000,3,256,256,3) where the 3 images are exactly the same?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have an array of 25000 RGB images of dimension 256x256x3 [25000,256,256,3]. Now, I want to replicate each of these images 2 times more and concatenate them such that the output array should be one dimension higher [25000,3,256,256,3]. This is channel last shape.

Comment: It would really help to show some Python code here for context.

Comment: Try img[:,[0,0,0],...]

Comment: @tstanisl That looks very compact. I would have tried a reshape, followed by tile.

Answer (score 0):

Without further clarification, I'm going to assume that you're working with basic NumPy arrays. In that case, you can use [`numpy.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) with `axis` specified:

```py
my_array = ...
n_copies = 3
replicated_array = np.stack([my_array for _ in range(n_copies)], axis=1)
```

Full example (dimensions changed for illustrative purposes):

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> a = np.array([[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]], [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]]])  # RGB images of dimension 2x2
>>> a
array([[[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0]]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 2, 3)
>>> 
>>> a_array = np.stack([a for _ in range(4)])  # Array of 4 images
>>> a_array.shape
(4, 2, 2, 3)
>>>
>>> # Replicate each of these images 9 times more and concatenate them
>>> # such that the output array should be one dimension higher 
>>> np.stack([a_array for _ in range(10)], axis=1).shape
(4, 10, 2, 2, 3)
```